# AutoHotKey String substitution

Tags: autohotkey

I am writing a small AHK script that defines a few simple HotStrings.

The concept is that when I type "Build QA1", the appropriate text associated with that HotString appears.

No problem there ...quite simple ...the issue is that I wish to have the string associated with the HotString appear as part of the substitute text ...in the example below, the results should be

Build QA1
Now is the time for all good men

The script below accomplishes this and works fine ...it does *exactly* what I ask, ***HOWEVER***, when I enter the HotString text and hit Enter or Tab or whatever initiates the HotString, that first line of text ( Build QA1 ) will "flash" on the screen as it is being substituted ...it makes it obvious that a HotString substitution is in operation ...

I would ideally like the HotString ( Build QA1 ) to remain as a part of the
substitute text without being replaced ...is this possible or is there a way to avoid the "flash" as that string is substituted ?

**::Build QA1:: 

send, Build QA1 

send, {enter} 



send, Now is the time for all good men

return**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
::b0::Build QA1::         ; automatic backspacing is not done to erase the abbreviation you type. 
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
clipboard := ""           ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the new text has arrived
clipboard =               ; copy this text:
(
Now is the time for all good men
)
ClipWait, 1              ; wait for the clipboard to contain data. 
if (!ErrorLevel)         ; if NOT ErrorLevel ClipWait found data on the clipboard  
Send ^v                  ; paste the text
Sleep, 300               ; don't change clipboard while pasting! (Sleep > 0)
clipboard := ClipSaved   ; restore original clipboard
VarSetCapacity(ClipSaved, 0) ; free  the memory of the variable ClipSaved
return
```

See [Hotstrings Options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options), [Clipboard](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm) and [ClipboardAll](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm#ClipboardAll) in the documentation.

Comment: Just what I needed ...many thanks !